# Почему зависимости в maven красные?

Tags: java, maven

Ну что не так? Почему они красные?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Что у вас за среда? Что она говорит по этому поводу? Работает ли код? Если нет, то какую ошибку выводит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

мне помогало обновление внесенных зависимостей[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: zeeetan, спасибо большое. Скажите, пожалуйста, а как попасть в это окно?

Comment: справа сбоку должен быть toolbar, там и находится окно maven, если его там нет, добавь его через идею:
View -> Tool Windows -> maven